# Move the box level generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm

Move the box is an iphone game which can be downloaded from:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/move-the-box/id491113310?mt=8

I need an idea to start creating an algorithm for generating levels for this game automatically.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy. Start from an empty board and apply the rules of the game BACKWARDS, i.e. add a row of three boxes, or make a move that could be made in its reverse direction in the real game (in your generator, boxes fall upwards).

Comment: antti.huima thanks for your answer but I couldn't get exactly what you mean.
Here is a sample level design for example: [link](http://softanbul.net/sample.png)
I would really appreciate it if you could demonstrate the required steps for generating this level.

Comment: In any this type of a puzzle game where the player has to reach a specific final state (here, empty board), problems can be generated by starting from the empty board and working backwards. Can you please post the exact rules of the game if you want me to give an example?